# Setting up Rake with Jenkins?

Tags: ruby, testing, logging, jenkins, rake

How can I report to Jenkins on individual task or steps of a rake-file?

I want as much info as possible about each sub task.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking for. Jenkins will capture the output of whatever rake command(s) you run. Do you want something more? Can you provide an example?

Comment: Is there a default format that rake can output to jenkins? I will create a rake file runing lots of subprocess and I will need to log these aswell.